# I'm trying to create a graph using matrix adjacency input , any ideas?

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to create a program that takes the matrix adjacency input from the user and then prints out a graph like so:
expected output:

A ---> B

B ---> C

C ---> A

So far I've managed to print the adjacency matrix input from the user.Here is my code below , any suggestions would be helpful:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix_create {

Scanner scan;
int matrix[][];
int row, column;

void create() {

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Matrix Creation");

    System.out.println("\nEnter number of rows :");
    row = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Enter number of columns :");
    column = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

    matrix = new int[row][column];
    System.out.println("Enter the data :");

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<column; j++) {

            matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();

        }
    }


    }


void display() {

    System.out.println("\nThe Matrix is :");

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<column; j++) {

            System.out.print("\t" + matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}



public static void main(String args[]) {

    Matrix_create obj = new Matrix_create();

    obj.create();
    obj.display();
}
}
```

Comment: First, enforce the matrix inputted to be square (`row==column`). Then, keep a translation array with letters (i.e `nodes=[A,B,C...]`). Next walk the matrix and when `matrix[i][j]==1` that means we have a link from `node[i]` to `node[j]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to print out the graph represented by an adjacency matrix, here you go:
Say, this is your adjacency matrix representing a undirected graph with 4 vertices:

```
0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
```

Let's write a method that will print out the edges of the graph:

**What should the method do?**

1. The method should take max of two parameters, one being the integer
   adjacency matrix and an integer denoting the number of nodes or
   vertices in your graph.
2. Within the method declare a `character` type variable and initialize
   it to `65`. Because 65 is the ASCII value of the uppercase **A**.
   This should be your starting node. *By doing this you can eliminate the need for keeping a seperate array of alphabets to track each vertex.*
3. Start iterating through your matrix. Now, for every row that you
   iterate, create another `character` type variable and initialize it
   to `65` again. This is the end node for every node that you are
   currently iterating.
4. After this decleration, start iterating over each column (`Row` of
   matrix represents start-node and `Column` represents end-node).
5. Within every column iteration, check if the edge is 1 .i.e
   `matrix[row][col] != 0`. If the edge is not `0`, print that edge.
6. Increment the end-node counter.
7. End the column iteration
8. Increment the start-node counter.
9. End the row iteration.

Finally, the method should look like this:

```
public static void printGraph(int[][] matrix, int nodes){
        char startNode = 65;
        for(int row = 0; row < nodes; row++){
            char endNode = 65;
            for(int col = 0; col < nodes; col++){
                int edge = matrix[row][col];
                if(edge != 0){
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(startNode) + " --> " + String.valueOf(endNode));
                }
                endNode++;
            }
            startNode++;
        }
    }
```

This produces the following output for the above mentioned input matrix:

```
A --> B
A --> C
B --> A
B --> C
B --> D
C --> A
C --> B
C --> C
D --> B
D --> C
```

**Note:** Whenever you are trying to implement any graph related problems, I would strongly suggest you to **not** make use of `adjacency matrix`. Rather make use of `adjacency list` to represent your graph. Because, adjacency matrix takes `O(V^2)` space where V is the number of vertices in the graph. Where as an adjacency list just takes `O(E)` space with E being the number of edges in the graph.

**Limitation:** The code fails to behave appropriately if the number of vertices in your graph exceeds 26, because the ASCII values after 90 will represent different symbols.

I hope this helped your learning.

Comment: Hi , thanks for that it has helped me understand quite a bit. Would you know how to do this for any matrix adjacency that the user inputs ?

Comment: You just need to take in the inputs using `Scanner`. First take input fornumber of nodes `int nodes`, then create `matrix[node][node]` and take individual `int` inputs. It's same as what you are doing. Then pass that matrix and number of nodes to this method.